# Mobile menu issue

Tags: html, css

URL:  getinjuryanswers.com

When I change height and margins of the mobile menu, it loses it's functionality.  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks.

**This is what I want it to be:**

```
#mobi-menu {
    background: url("http://getinjuryanswers.com/wp-content/themes/Bajaj/images/mobile-menu-icon.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 #203c4f;
    clear: both;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 0;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
}
```

**This is what it currently is:**

```
#mobi-menu {
    background: url("http://getinjuryanswers.com/wp-content/themes/Bajaj/images/mobile-menu-icon.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 #203c4f;
    clear: both;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    float: none;
    height: 30px;
    margin: 40px 12px 2px 0;
    visibility: visible;
    width: 100%;
}
```

HTML CODE:

```
<aside class="widget-area header-widget-area">
<div id="mobi-menu">
<span>Menu</span>
</div>
<section id="black-studio-tinymce-2" class="widget widget_black_studio_tinymce">
<section id="nav_menu-2" class="widget widget_nav_menu">
</aside>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like another layer is on top of the menu, you can try to make it on top again by adding:

```
#mobi-menu {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you set `margin: 0` the menu icon is covered by the first section (#black-studio-tinymce-2), so never gets clicked.

It is not clear what you are trying to do with that section when on a mobile, as it does not display. You could set it to `display: none;` if you don't need it, or move it somewhere else.